# Does query execution and performance will defer using combination of 'Where' with 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' and only 'FirstOrDefaultAsync'?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I have come across code that uses two different statements to retrieve items from DB.

First

```
_dbContext.Storage.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.FkUser == UserId).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Second

```
_dbContext.Storage.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.FkUser == UserId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I am more curious to understand is there are any execution, performance and memory usage difference in both code snippets?

> *Note: Application created in .netcore and using EF for DB operations.*

Comment: My experience tells me that the two pieces of code are identical.

Comment: Shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: if you absolutely need to know: run a SQL profiler, but: it is certainly *meant* to compose down to the same thing

Comment: The query will be the same. There might be a slight overhead(very minimum) because two functions `Where,FirstOrDefault` will be called on one,on the other only `FirstOrDefault` will be called.